# Как прижать элемент к краю окна если он находится в контейнере с max-width

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, озадачился просто проблемой, есть бутстрап сетка.

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="content1">123</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="content2">123</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Так вот, у контейнера max-width=1200, нужно под .content1 добавить полоску ведущую от левого края окна браузера и до конца текста внутри него, и нужно добавить фон у .content2 так чтобы он был прижат к правому краю окна.
[Посмотреть](http://prntscr.com/bpg8qv)

Помогите , ато проблема вроде простая, а мозги не варят

Comment: это надо сделать средствами bootstrap ?  и для лучшего понимания добавьте разметку в сниппет ,.

Comment: Да всё равно, главное чтобы адаптивно было, поэтому озадачился так как сетка бутстрап мешает это сделать) Я уже и через before и position: absolute делал, но при изменении размера экрана не хватает ширины полоски

Comment: пример в снипет добавьте , а то закроют

Comment: ваша разметка несоответствует вашему скриншоту - там явно нет 50/50

Comment: Ну я просто для примера написал, понятно что там сетка идет примерно 8 и 4, у меня просто проблема с самой полосой за сеткой

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rn9sLmd3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/rn9sLmd3/1/  вот полоска на весь текст

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
section {
  position: relative;
}
.content-right {
  position: absolute!important;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.content1 h2{
  position: relative; 
}
.content1 h2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: orange;
}
.content1 h2 > span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange
}

.content2 {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .content-right {
    position: relative!important;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;    
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.0</h1>
    <p class="lead">Starter template with CSS and JS included.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#fork">Fork this fiddle</a></p>
  </div>
</div>


<section class="clearfix">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <div class="content1">
        <h2><span>Так вот, у контейнера</span></h2>
          <p>Так вот, у контейнера max-width=1200, нужно под .content1 добавить полоску ведущую от левого края окна браузера и до конца текста внутри него, и нужно добавить фон у .content2 так чтобы он был прижат к правому краю окна. Посмотреть</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 content-right">
        <div class="content2">
          <h3>Так вот, у контейнера</h3>
          <p>Так вот, у контейнера </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное :)